# Terminal in mac weird user?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, osx-yosemite

Whenever i login into terminal i get the following before my user:

```
Last login: Wed May 13 12:52:32 on ttys000
stange-name:~ andy$
```

Where is jhps-gardens coming from?? I have no idea what it is, or where it is coming from. I know im not in that directory. And i haven't switched user. If anyone can help that would be amazing.

[image: terminal window]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though i found the answer:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName name-you-want
```